# Google Appscript Error Exception issue with recordset

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

To be clear, I looked at other posts in Stackoverflow on this issue before posting the problem.  So far nothing has helped so i am reaching out to the community to help.  The error is:

> Error  Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature
> for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

Here is what i have in a function called code.gs

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Main");
var configSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Config"); 


function createid()
{

  
  var colnum = getColIndexByNameandRow("UID",ss,1)

   

};
```

UID is an actual row header in my spreadsheet, and I want to return the column number from the sheet.  I developed a function that returns the column Index.  The function is listed below

```
function getColIndexByNameandRow(colName,mysheet,rs) 
{
 
  /*
    ColName is the name of the column your looking for, string value
    mysheet is the recordset for the sheet you are searching for the column
    (R)ow (S)tart (rs) is the row position where you want the column search to start
  */
  if (rs==undefined) rs=1;
  
  var numColumns = mysheet.getLastColumn();

  var row = mysheet.getRange(rs, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) 
    {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
};
```

I know my ss active sheet declaration is working because the line before it `var numColumns = mysheet.getLastColumn();` works fine and returns the number of rows.  The following line chokes every time it runs:

```
 var row = mysheet.getRange(rs, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
```

Whats interesting is I am using the same function with another project, and its flawless n no issues.

I have tried changing .getValues() to .getDisplayValues() with no success.

Anyone got anything else I can try.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem.  I renamed the ss SpreadsheetApp to the mainsheet, and it worked. I am not sure why that is, but it doesn't seem to like the use of ss as a SpreadsheetApp.  I added my sample test that worked

```
function test(){

var val = getColIndexByNameandRow("UID",mainsheet,1)

Logger.log(val)


}
```